# Can I run socket io server on codesandbox along with the app?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to run socket io server in my codesandbox project with my react app at the same time but It doesn't seem to work.

my package is containing the following:

```
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"react-scripts start\"",
    "server": "nodemon --exec 'ts-node' server/index.ts localhost 8080"
  },
```

I do no think my scripts are being detected by the codesandbox because I have tried deleting everything from them and my react app is working - without the server part. Can someone explain how does codesandbox handle those stuff and if you have an example how to run react + server in the same sandbox.

Comment: Remember that "It doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description. _What_ doesn't work? Are there errors? Does the code not even run? Does the code run but the server doesn't start? Does the server start but it doesn't respond when called? Does it respond but not upgrade websocket connections? And if you don't know: find out. Add logging, start logging, gain insight.

Comment: There are no errors. Like I mentioned nothing in the "scripts" is being detected at all.

Comment: those words don't work together though: scripts in package.json are instructions can you can issue to `npm`, there is no detecting at play. So: what are you running? Did you test `npm run server` on its own? Does that work? (And remember: put those details in your post, that's where they go =) Also, rather than using `concurrently`, it might be useful to install `npm-run-all` instead so your start script can be written as `"start": "run-p server react"` with an extra `"react": "react-scripts start"`. Separate your tasks, so you can test them individually, then compose them after they pass.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did test them separately but it seems like it doesn't detect the package.json scripts at all,  whatever command I put in it. I just tested the code outside of the codesandbox on my machine and it starts the server + the react app as it should. I will probably try to recreate the sandbox project and see if I have messed something while working on it.

Comment: Did you restart the sandbox after making the changes?